# Virtual filesystem listing

Tags: c++, c

I want to store a file/folder listing in a virtual tree/list. Maybe a vector or similar. Anybody has an idea how to manage this? I have two type of items: Folder (node) and file. I have to emulate different sub levels of folders.
It has to be similar to a Treeview. That every node can have a subnode that can have a subnode and so fort. I need to have the possibility to delete a file or folder (and its subfolder & files).

Maybe a link or a hint will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of polymorphism.

```
class FileSystemElement{
...
}

class Folder: public FileSystemElement{
...
public:
    std::list<FileSystemelement*> subfolders;
}

class File: public FileSystemElement{
...
}
```

and then maybe something like this:

```
class FileSystem{
public:
    FileSystem();
    ~FileSystem();
    void removeFile(std::string path);
    void addFile(std::string path, void* data, size_t size);
    std::list<File*> filesInFolder(std::string path);
    ...
private:
    std::list<FileSystemElement*> filesystem;
}
```

Deleting and adding can e.g. be done by the normal `std::list` `add` and `remove` methods

Comment: hint: use the composite design pattern and add some basic functionalities to the base class. that way you can write concise code.

Comment: If performance and nested path lookups aren't a consideration this is a workable idea that is easy to implement.